# c# webBrowser.Document: reloading page after postback

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I am working on a simple application that automatically browses in a page that contains two dropdown menus and a button. The page looks like this:

> ------DropDown1-------
>
> ------DropDown2-------
>
> -------Button---------

Now, the problem is, the contents of `DropDown2` is dynamically generated by the selection of `Dropdown1`.

I wrote code like this in c#:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElement elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("DropDown1");
    elem.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "1");
    elem.RaiseEvent("onChange");
    HtmlElement elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("DropDown2");
    elem.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "5");
    elem.RaiseEvent("onChange");
}
```

After raising the `onChange` event, the browser loads the new values but I can't get and set the `DropDown2` value because the document still thinks `DropDown2`s values are empty.

How can I get and set the new values that are generated in `DropDown2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have found the solution by invoking "__doPostBack" script after raising onChange event. when i invove the doPostBack, the document reloads and so i can retrieve the new values. heres the code:

```
    private void BeginOperation()
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("somewebpage", false);
        Task = 0;
    }
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement elem;

        switch (Task)
        {
            case 0:
                //HtmlDocument mydoc = webBrowser1.Document;
                 elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ddlCity");
                MessageBox.Show(elem.All.Count.ToString());
                elem.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "1");
                //elem.RaiseEvent("onChange");
                object[] args = {"someparameters"};
                webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("__doPostBack",args);
                Task++;
            break;
            case 1:
                elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ddlDistrict");
                elem.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "2");
                elem.RaiseEvent("onChange");
                object[] args2 = {"someparameters"};
                webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("__doPostBack",args2);
                Task++;
            break;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem you're encountering is because the code you've written doesn't wait for the postback to occur. So what happens is....

```
|---> The page finishes loading, triggering your DocumentCompleted method
|---> You set the selectedIndex on DropDown1
|---> You raise the onChange event for DropDown1
|       |---> The page starts posting-back (1)
|---> You (attempt to) set the selectedIndex on DropDown2
|---> You raise the onChange event for DropDown2
|       |---> The page starts posting-back (2)
|
...
...
...
|---> The page finishes re-loading from from postback (2)
```

Basically, what you need to do is *wait* after triggering the postback for the page to re-load. The inelegant, brittle and almost certain to break/not work way of doing this is to trigger a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), or similar, so that after a period of time (as long as the postback takes to occur) you can then continue on setting the selectedIndex for DropDown2. The better option would be to do something like this:

```
|---> The page finishes loading, triggering your DocumentCompleted method
|---> You attach a new EventHandler to DocumentCompleted that contains the 
|     code for changing the selectedIndex on DropDown2 and REMOVE this 
|     eventhandler
|---> You set the selectedIndex on DropDown1
|---> You raise the onChange event for DropDown1
|---> Your code in the DocumentCompleted handler finishes executing


|---> // This is the DocumentCompleted handler that you assign above
|---> You set the selectedIndex on DropDown2
|---> You raise the onChange event for DropDown2
|---> Your code in the DocumentCompleted handler finishes executing
```

There are more elegant ways of doing this, but this is probably the simplest to explain.

Comment: i thought of that too but "DocumentCompleted" Handler doesnt run after postback. selecting an item in dropDown1 just fires a function to populate DropDown2. so Documentcompleted is fired once. Also another note, when i put a delay after onChange with System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); the thread just waits to finish postback for 5 sec and it doesnt work.. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this.  I've been looking for a solution to a similar problem for days...
In my case, I had a single dropdown menu for which the items in the list were updated during the "onchange" event.  Invoking *_*_doPostBack updates the WebBrowserReadyState allowing me a way to wait for the "onchange" event to complete before scraping the new dropdown list values.